# Exportar lista PDF a Excel

Tags: python, excel

Soy nuevo en scripting y más con Python. A un amigo le llego una lista de precios y me pide ayuda a ver si la podemos pasar a .xlsx y de ahí manipularla y cuando la intento exportar a un `.txt` por ejemplo, pierde todo el formato:

### Lista:

[image: Lista PDF]

### Lo que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Para leer y generar el ".txt" uso este código:

```
import fitz

lista_pdf = "DGB Precios 24-8-21.pdf"
documento = fitz.open(lista_pdf)
salida = open("lista" + ".txt", "wb")

for pagina in documento
    texto = pagina.getText().encode("uft8")
    salida.write(texto)
    salida.write(b"\n-----\n")
    
    salida.close()
```

Lo que quisiera obtener es mínimo eliminar todo el contenido superior y dejar a partir de la línea que dice  "00010 MOLINOS RIO DE LA PLATA S.A"  y no logro dar con ese formato o bueno seria lo ideal mantener el formato de la lista PDF.

¿Alguna sugerencia? muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio, también lee [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Las imágenes no son bien recibidas en el sitio, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/479348/edit) tu pregunta colocando el código como texto por favor.

Comment: Hola manito, ignora comentarios como los de arriba, ese tipo de gente abren preguntas de usuarios nuevos solo para dejar ese copy-paste, son conocidos como reputation-wh..res. Mira, en los siguientes comentarios te dejare 3 opciones para que puedas exportar a excel.

Comment: 1era opcion: Si el pdf tiene OCR (es decir, no es una 'imagen' pura, sino que cada imagen esta hasheado con su texto), entonces puedes darle un copiar a la tabla entera y en una consola abre el python, importa pandas y haz pandas.read_clipboard. Esta es la documentacion https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html

Comment: 2da opcion: Usa pytesseract. Esto es un OCR que te ayudara a leer el pdf y conseguir su texto en formato tabla https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Comment: 3era opcion: Crea una cuenta de AWS. esto requiere que pongas tu tarjeta de credito/debito, pero no te preocupes que tienes una capa gratuita por 365 dias en muchos servicios. En la barra de busqueda, escribe 'REKOGNITION'. Esto es una api de reconocimiento de texto/tablas/formas. Mete tu pdf y luego descarga el csv que te dara la api.

Comment: Sorry que no te los deje como respuesta, pero aqui son tan berrinchudos "por hacerte la tarea" que me lloverian un monton de votos negativos, solo por querer ayudarte ;)

Comment: Puedes convertirlo con alguna aplicacion online como smallpdf